# No data fetched for symbol XAUUSD using YahooDailyReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

`GOLD 1 OZ (XAUUSD=X)` this is Yahoo Finance Gold ticket.
But

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime 
from ta import *
gspc = pdr.get_data_yahoo('XAUUSD', #or 'XAUUSD=X'
                          start=datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 3), 
                          end=datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15),
                          interval='m')
```

give me error

> RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol XAUUSD using
>   YahooDailyReader

What ticket need? Where can i find the right one gold ticket?

Answer (score 0):

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_ta as ta
XAU= yf.Ticker("^XAU")
# Download the stock price data from Yahoo Finance API
data = XAU.history(start="2023-10-19", end="2023-11-19", interval="5m")
print(data)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include an explanation?

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.